# How to check if elements in an array are sorted according to number of occurences?

Tags: java, arrays, list, sorting

I want to check if the elements in an array are sorted according to the number of their occurrences in. This is assuming they are already grouped if elements are the same.
`int [] y = {7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 5, 5, 5, 5}` should return `false` while `int [] y = {5, 5, 5, 5, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8}` should return `true`. There are four 5s, three 7s and two 8s, so it should be arranged that way.

This is what I have so far:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;


public class testing2 {

  public static void main(String[] args){
    int [] y = {7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 5, 5, 5, 5};
    System.out.println(isSorted(y));  // should return false

  }

  public static boolean isSorted(int[] y){

    HashMap<Integer,Integer> hash = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();

    for(int i=0; i<y.length; i++){
      if(hash.containsKey(y[i])){
        hash.put(y[i], hash.get(y[i]) + 1);
      } else {
        hash.put(y[i], 1);
      }
    }
    System.out.println(hash);
    return true;  // code is not complete yet
  }
}
```

It would print:

```
{5=4, 7=3, 8=2}
true
```

So now I have the number of occurrences for each element. What do I do next?

Comment: `isSorted` will always return true, and what do you want to do next?

Comment: *How to check*, so basically you want to say 'its not ordered' and 'its ordered' ? if its like that, you could iterate every item while counting, then if the number changes, check it whether its number is larger (or smaller) than previous number set..

Comment: @LKTN.25 yeah the return true part isn't completed yet. I have the occurrences, now I want to see if my array y[] = {7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 5, 5, 5, 5} is sorted according to number of occurrences in descending order or not. It's not as the number of occurrences is 3, 2, 4 but it should be 4, 3, 2

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this in a single pass of the array; here are some hints:

While you are iterating through the array, keep track of the current `number` (e.g. 5, 7 or 8) and the `quantity`. When you finish the next group of `number`s, compare it the previous `number`/`quantity`. Then, return true or false appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer keeping your direction of using `HashMap`, there is one way to continue:

- Use `LinkedHashMap` instead, so when you iterate thru the map, you are iterating in the order you put that in the map
- Iterate thru the map, and see if each entry is having count `<` prev entry. Pseudo  Code:

  ```
  int prevCount = MAX_INT;
  for (entry : map) {
      currentCount = entry.getValue()
      if (currentCount > prevCount) {
          return false
      }
      prevCount = currentCount
  }
  return true;
  ```

---

Or, you can have one single-pass on the array (pseudo-code):

```
 prevCount = MAX_INT
 currentCount = 0;
 for (i = 0...array.length) {
     increment currentCount 

     // if i points to last number in group
     if (i is the last element of array, OR
             next element is not equals to current element) {
         if currentCount > prevCount {
             return false;
         }
         prevCount = currentCount;
         currentCount = 0;
     }
}
```